# Linux copy all files and folders except for one folder to another folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, copy

I have the following content in a folder

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
File 1
File 2
File 3
```

I'm trying to use the command line to move all folders and files except Folder 1, to Folder 1. That is, Folder 1 will have Folder 2, Folder 3, File 1, File 2, File 3 after the move.

How do I exclude Folder 1 from the move?

I was scared to try this:
`$ cp -r /Folder 1`, because that would include Folder 1 too.

I'm on the latest version of Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
mv !(Folder\ 1) Folder\ 1/
```

This will recursively move all files and folders in the current directory to Folder 1 except Folder 1.

This will also work with cp, but it was unclear what you wanted since your example used cp but your question stated you wanted to move items.

Comment: (1) It's the job of the shell to expand this `!(exclusion)` syntax. Some shells support this, others don't; the syntax is not portable. We don't know what the OP's shell is. Your answer can be improved: which shells support the syntax? (2) What is the `-R` option in `mv`?

Comment: I just got down to this, and keep getting this: `mv: invalid option -- 'R`.

Comment: It works if you remove the `-R`. `mv` moves recursively by default.